# ubuntu, не сломать или восстановить

Tags: linux, ubuntu, резервное-копирование

Всем привет, поставил себе ubuntu на рабочий ПК, как основную ОС.
Опыта работы в linux только на уровне установки и удаления пакетов и работе с файлами и директориями (для веб-разработки достаточно).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы случайно не сломать ОС, точнее
какие именно ПО нужно поставить, чтобы можно было создать точку восстановления системы вместе с моими установленными пакетами ?

У меня уже был печальный опыт с ubuntu, после команды `sudo apt upgrade` и перезапуска ПК, графический интерфейс перестал загружаться.. Выводился `tty`, выйти из него нельзя было, перепробовал всевозможные варианты из интернета.. Только переключался между `tty1..tty2..`

К сожалению после подобных ситуаций во время работы нет времени долго пытаться разрулить проблему, пытаясь понять в чем проблема и решить ее. 
Хотелось бы иметь возможность, быстро восстановить настроенную систему с установленными ПО (в момент создания контрольной точки).

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть возможности этого добиться? 
Может есть какие-то хорошие пакеты для этого, чтобы смог даже через `tty` запустить и откатиться? 
Или может скопировать всю файловую на флешку, а потом через livecd загрузить все на жесткий диск ?

Comment: У меня `sudo apt upgrade` делалось скриптом ежедневно в течении шести лет и ничего не ломалось. Уверен, что причина в чём-то другом. Скорее всего вы какие-то другие команды через `sudo` вводили, не понимая, что они делают.

Comment: Лично я, когда знакомился с линуксом, шёл другим путём - писал скрипты, которые бэкапили на удалённый репозиторий конфиги всех моих программ и восстанавливали их, а также устанавливали все нужные мне программы в один клик. Тем самым я убил кучу зайцев - выучил основы баша, гита и теперь не потеряю важные данные, даже если мой компьютер похитят инопланетяне.

Comment: `BorgBackup` неполх.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, скорей всего это произошло при обновлении релиза... проблемы часто возникают, если, например, часть пакетов не установилась, а пользователь этого не заметил и отправился в ребут...

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте разные разделы. Системный `/` -> `/dev/sda1`. Домашний `/home` -> `/dev/sda2`. Скопируйте запасную копию системного раздела на домашнюю директорию. Далее чтобы всё вернуть копируйте обратно.

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/user/backup.iso bs=64k`

`dd if=/home/user/backup.iso of=/dev/sda1 bs=64k`